# Workflow of editing in Premiere and Color Grading in Davinci

Tags: premiere, davinci-resolve, workflow

I am new to color grading in Davinci Resolve (Studio) and am not sure about how the workflow should go.

As far as I understand there are three options:

1. Color Correct all Clips and render in losless codec (More work as unused clips get processed too)
2. Edit the film, than only grade used clips and relink them in premiere (Not so nice as you can't see the hole think while grading)
3. Somehow import the Premiere Project to Davinci with all cuts

I am not sure how the third one would work, espacially while using many Nested sequences.

So what is the best/official way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: There rarely is one best or official workflow. Every team and even every project is different. Tools get used in different ways. You will need to experiment and find what works for you.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Sure I know, but I guess there are allready ways that others know which won't work/are bad. So I wanted to get some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is the following:

- Sync audio in PluralEyes and export to Premiere.
- Edit in Premiere before color correction or grading. Yeah, log footage looks crap, but you should be able to edit just fine. Apply a LUT temporarily if you absolutely can't stand it.
- Export to FCPro XML from Premiere and import into DaVinci.
- Color correct in DaVinci
- Color grade and add any other color effects
- Correct audio in DaVinci using Fairlight (yum!)
- Export

That's what works for me. YMMV and others may have a totally different flow. But this lets me use PluralEyes which does way better and more complex syncing based on audio than DaVinci or Premiere. It also gives me my hotkeys for editing in Premiere and the best color grader in the biz which is DaVinci along with Fairlight which is great for audio.

Comment: Thank you, sounds good. How far can FCPro XML go? I use quite a lot of nested sequences, After Effect Timelines directly in Premiere Pro and all Effects, can Davinci recreate all of this accuratly?

Comment: I noticed my transitions disappeared when exporting from Premiere. So I literally just user it for cutting. I wouldn't rely heavily or assuming anything other than tracks, cuts and synchronization. Other than that, all bets are off as far as I'm concerned. Perhaps others have had more luck.

Comment: Just want to add: The main reason I'm still using Premiere for editing is the shortcut keys I'm used to and it's a good workflow from PluralEyes to Premiere to DaVinci. DaVinci is horrible at multi-cam audio sync and going from PluralEyes direct to DaVinci is painful. Going via Premiere is way easier and more reliable I've found.

Comment: Thank you, hmm. I really need deeper editing in Premiere Pro (I don't want to switch to Davinci as I have a ton of shortcuts/scripts for Premiere and I need to use team projects.) So I guess your workflow won't be usable for me. Thank you still.